# No primary server available when failover happens: MongoDB, Node.js, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently facing an issue when failover happens in mongodb replica set. The app fails to reconnect to the newly elected primary server and fails to perform all subsequent write operations.

Restarting app reconnects successfully.

The failover happens instantly and a new primary is elected. However, the app fails to connect to the new primary.

mongodb version: 3.2.6
mongoose version: 4.3.4
node.js version:0.10.26

Comment: Need more details. What does the mongoose.connect code look like? You can star the server details.

Comment: This is similar to https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3634, but no solution was provided

Comment: this has been resolved by replacing hostname in rs.conf and replacing all with ips

Comment: can you plz share little bit more information. kindly share the configuration of replica sets like what priority you have assigned to each replica set so incase of failure after voting other machine will take over as primary. --- second share your connection string --- hosting you are using and all your replica sets are reachable from main server e.g. white listed ping from api server to check all db servers.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing a similar problem then I just changed

```
mongoose.connect(db)
```

to

```
mongoose.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true})
```

and now it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I have a primary, secondary and an arbiter set up running in three different nodes. This is how I connect using mongoose and the failover works perfectly fine.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pwd@a.com:27017,b.com:27017,c.com:27017/dbName');
```

So, everything expect mongodb:// are variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but it turned out to be that I was trying to access from a non-whitelisted IP.

Answer (score 0):

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
use like this, it will work fine.